# Want to show specific posts to show on specific days every week

Tags: php, wordpress

Below is the summary :-

I have 8 different posts with a custom post type say " Class Banners "

So one of the post will always be showing on my site's home page for the upcoming fitness class for the user to see.

I have 8 Classes and so i created 8 posts this is how I want them to display :-

“Post 1” displayed Sunday 8.00am to Monday 9.30am

“Post 2” displayed Monday 9.30am to Monday 7.00pm

“Post 3” displayed Monday 7.00pm to Tuesday 6.30pm

“Post 4” displayed Tuesday 6.30pm to Wednesday 7.30pm

“Post 5” displayed Wednesday 7.30pm to Thursday 6.30pm

“Post 6” displayed Thursday 6.30pm to Friday 9.00am

“Post 7” displayed Friday 9.00am to Saturday 9.00am

“Post 8” displayed Saturday 9.00am to Sunday 8.00am

I need them to display on these specific days and time each week.

**Now what I want is :- **

I need to get those specific time queries, I know how to display each post individually.

I am just not getting it worked out to get those specific time intervals for each week so I can have 8 queries and when a specific query is met, I can show specific post my-self.

I know php, and I know where to place the queries in template but not sure how wordpress will take those queries and the right syntax that will go with wp code.

Can someone assist on this.

Thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve is possible.. but it is freaking complex. Would it be an option for you to group the post by day alone and not by day and time? you could specify the time in a custom field and the job would be done. Let me know if this is a viable option for you, I will point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$day = date("N");
$hour = date("H");
$minute = date("i";


$post1 = "Hello";
$post2 = "World";
$post3 = "I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't let you do that.";
$post4 = "I'll be back";
$post5 = "xyz";
$post6 = "abc";
$post7 = "alphabetic";
$post8 = "numeric";

if($day == "1") // if day is monday
{
 if($hour < 9)
 {
  echo $post8;
 }
 elseif($hour > 9)
 {
  echo $post1;
 }
 else
 {
  if($minute < 30)
  {
   echo $post8;
  }
  else
  {
   echo $post1;
  }
 }
}
... // Same for rest of week
```

Does this point you in the right direction??

Comment: Yes Jdoonam, It atleast guided me towards the way I wanted it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$current = date('w') * 100 + date('H') + date('i') / 60 - 8;
$splits = array(101.5, 111, 210.5, 311.5, 410.5, 501, 601, 700);
$posts = array("Post 1", "Post 2", "Post 3", "Post 4", "Post 5", "Post 6", "Post 7", "Post 8");
$post = "Time processing error";

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    if ($current < $splits[$i]) {
        $post = $posts[$i];
        break;
    }
}
```